# Replacing ggplot2 legend key for geom_line with symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot of prices for three stocks, which I normalise by taking the percentage change from the beginning of the period I am looking at. This seems to work fine, but instead of the coloured lines on a grey background that currently make up the legend key, I would like squares or circles of colour next to the key label.

Is this even possible in ggplot2? Any pointers, however brief, appreciated. Code to produce the chart follows below.

```
Date <- c("2011-09-19","2011-09-20","2011-09-21","2011-09-22",
                "2011-09-23","2011-09-26","2011-09-27","2011-09-28","2011-09-29","2011-09-30")
CoA <- c(100,100,95,93,88,91,98,109,115,106)
CoB <- c(16.5,16.8,17.2,17,17.5,16.5,16,15.5,16.1,16.3)
CoC <- c(3.2,3.18,3.15,3.12,3.15,3.1,3.08,3.11,3.35,3.42)
prices <- data.frame(Date,CoA,CoB,CoC)
changes <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(prices),ncol=ncol(prices)))
changes[,1]=prices[,1]
for(i in 2:ncol(prices)){ # calculate changes in price
    changes[,i]= (prices[,i]-prices[,i][1])/prices[,i][1]
}
colnames(changes) <- colnames(prices)
changes <- melt(changes, id = "Date")
changes$Date <- as.Date(as.character(changes$Date))
chart1 <- ggplot(data=changes,aes(x=changes$Date,y=changes$value,colour=changes$variable))
chart1 <- chart1 + geom_line(lwd=0.5) + ylab("Change in price (%)") + xlab("Date") +
    labs(colour="Company")
print(chart1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define new geom like this:

```
GeomLine2 <- proto(GeomLine, {
    objname <- "line2"
    guide_geom <- function(.) "polygon"
    default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour = "black", size=0.5, linetype=1, alpha = 1, fill = "grey20")
     })
geom_line2 <- GeomLine2$build_accessor()

chart1 <- ggplot(data=changes,aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=variable, fill = variable))
chart1 <- chart1 + geom_line2(lwd=0.5) + ylab("Change in price (%)") + xlab("Date") +
  labs(colour="Company",  fill = "Company")
print(chart1)
```

Not sure but note that this will not work in the next version of ggplot2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot` the legend matches the plot itself.  So, to get circles or squares in the legend you need to add circles or squares to the plot.

This can be done with `geom_point(shape=...)`.  `shape=1` generates circles, `shape=7` generates squares.

```
chart1 + geom_point(shape=7)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it is good to have confirmation of something I had already suspected. Is there some way to work around this limitation?