# override.aes (change key grob) when using geom_text like geom_shape with FontAwesome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using geom_text to display custom symbols (male and female symbols from the FontAwesome font) in varying size on a map (gender gaps). This works great and was an easy way to use meaningful symbols, but I'm not sure it's the best way.

I'd like to customise the size legend so that the female symbol is displayed as the key. The default is the letter "a" in the size legend. This is changeable, [as this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405823/changing-the-symbol-in-the-legend-key-in-ggplot2), by using a mock point and then overriding the `shape` param using `override.aes`.

Unfortunately, I am unable to use the female/male symbols in this way, the warning is:

> 1: In grid.Call.graphics(L_points, x$x, x$y, x$pch, x$size) :
>     pch value '61827' is invalid in this locale

and I cannot find a parameter that would allow me to modify the legend key shape font.

Is this somehow possible using the internal magic of ggplot, or should I give up and use Photoshop?

Here's some toy data that throws the error (unless Stackoverflow mangles the symbols, if so you can find them at the [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) homepage):

```
df <- expand.grid(x = factor(seq(1:5)), y = factor(1), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
df$Count = seq(1:5)
df$Label = c('', '','', '', '')

# A plot
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(data = df, aes( x = x, y = y, label = Label, size = Count)) + 
    geom_point(colour = NA) +
    geom_text(show_guide = FALSE, family = "FontAwesome") +  
    guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "black", shape = utf8ToInt("")))) +
    scale_size(range = c(2, 10))

p
```

Comment: Have you tried this approach, using unicode instead of a special font? https://github.com/kmiddleton/rexamples/blob/master/ggplot2%20male-female%20symbols.R