# Reorder colors and legend of multi-line graph, and change legend icon

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have data for a number of geographical regions, each of which has an associated description and time-series data. For example:

```
---in file "data.csv":
ID,Region,Year,Value
9,Manhattan,2010,5
9,Manhattan,2011,6
10,Brooklyn,2010,6
10,Brooklyn,2011,7
11,Bronx,2010,8
11,Bronx,2011,6
12,New Jersey,2010,7
12,New Jersey,2011,5
```

(This table is formed by reshaping an earlier table with one row per region, but that's not relevant here.) I'd like to plot this data with `ggplot2` and include both ID and description in the legend. Here's my best attempt:

```
#! /usr/bin/env RSCRIPT

library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- fread("data.csv")[,Label:=paste(ID, " (", Region, ")", sep="")]
png("plot.png")
gg <- ggplot(data=dt,aes(x=Year,y=Value,group=ID,colour=Label)) +
    geom_line() + geom_label(aes(label=ID))
print(gg)
dev.off()
```

The result:

[image: sample plot]

I'd like to make two changes:

1. Assign colors by numerical, not alphabetical, value—so that "9 (Manhattan)" gets red, "10 (Bronx)" gets greenish-yellow, and so forth—while keeping the automatic color palette. I'd like to avoid manual color selection with `scale_colour_manual()` and its ilk. My actual data has varying numbers of regions, up to about 20 per chart.
2. Change the colored icon in the legend from a lowercase A to the region ID (so a red 9, a greenish-yellow 10, and so on). This would let me use the Region field alone as legend text, rather than "ID (Region)".

Comment: For the first, you can set the levels of your factor in the order you want prior to plotting.

Comment: Is there a way of doing that automatically, just by inspecting dt[,ID] or similar?

Comment: if you just call `as.factor(dt$ID)` it will make the factor levels default to order in your data frame which looks like enough for this case, you might also want to looks `library(forcats)` for additional functions for easy factor leveling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405823/changing-the-symbol-in-the-legend-key-in-ggplot2

Comment: @NathanDay The Stack Overflow question you linked works for setting a new constant legend symbol, but not setting a variable one; I tried imitating it by adding `guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=as.character(dt[,ID])))` to the plot object and only got `Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`.

Comment: I am not aware of way you can accomplish your precise goal in ggplot2, you may have to make a compromise

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28685563/2461552) looks like it might do what you want.  Note that there is some extra code to get the letters into shapes via `utf8ToInt`.

Answer (score 2):

The current labeling is because the alphabetic ordering of `9:12` is `c("10", "11", "12", "9")`. You can change it manually, or you can use something like `mixedsort` from `gtools` to do it, here using `dplyr` and `magrittr` instead of `data.table`:

```
dt %<>%
  mutate(Label = paste0(dt$ID, " (", dt$Region, ")") %>%
           factor(levels = mixedsort(unique(.))))
```

Changing the labels in the legend is a bit harder, primarily because they have two characters (instead of just one). If your labels were all a single character, you could just do something like this:

```
ggplot(data=dt,aes(x=Year,y=Value,group=ID,colour=Label)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label=ID), show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c("A","B","C","D")
                                                  , size = 3)))
```

[image]

However, you cannot (to my knowledge) use multiple characters in a shape. So, I resort to my common fall back: generating the complicated legend that I want as a separate plot and stitching them together with `cowplot`.

First, store the plot you want to make *without a legend*

```
plotPart <-
  ggplot(data=dt,aes(x=Year,y=Value,group=ID,colour=Label)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label=ID)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Then, modify the original data to limit down to just one entry per region with the regions as factors in the same order as the labels are (here, using `dplyr` but you could modify to use `data.table` instead). Pass that in to `ggplot` and generate the layout you want. I have the regions on the left still, but you could move them to the right with `scale_y_discrete(position = "right")`.

```
legendPart <-
  dt %>%
  select(ID, Region, Label) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(.)) %>%
  arrange(desc(ID)) %>%
  mutate(Region = factor(Region, levels = Region)) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = 1
        , y = Region
        , color = Label
        , label = ID)) +
  geom_label() +
  theme(legend.position = "none"
        , axis.title = element_blank()
        , axis.text.x = element_blank()
        , axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
        , panel.grid = element_blank()
        )
```

Then, load `cowplot`. Note that it resets the default `theme` so you need to manually over ride it (unless you like the `cowplot` theme) with `theme_set`:

```
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_minimal())
```

Then, use `plot_grid` to stitch everything together. The simplest version has no arguments, but doesn't look great:

```
plot_grid(plotPart, legendPart)
```

gives

[image]

But, we can control the spacing with `rel_widths` (you will need to play with it to fit your actual data and aspect ratio):

```
plot_grid(plotPart
          , legendPart
          , rel_widths = c(0.9, 0.2)
          )
```

gives

[image]

I personally like to "squish" the legend a bit, so I usually nest the legend within another `plot_grid` call, here including a title for good measure:

```
plot_grid(
  plotPart
  , plot_grid(
    ggdraw()
    , ggdraw() + draw_label("Legend")
    , legendPart
    , ggdraw()
    , rel_heights = c(1,1,3,2)
    , ncol = 1
  )
  , rel_widths = c(0.9, 0.2)
)
```

gives

[image]

Which I believe meets the requirements from your question, though you will still likely want to tweak it to match your prefered style, etc.