# Change ggplot2::geom_line legend shape to a "dot" similar to ggplot2::geom_point's legend shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

The overriding effort here is to change the legend shape for `geom_line` to a `geom_point` "dot", but retain the `geom_line` in the plot. I would be grateful if someone could demonstrate how to create a cleaner `geom_line2()` function (see below) which shows the `geom_point` "dot" object in the legend.

I know that one could layer `geom_point` and effect `guides(color = FALSE)` for the `geom_line`. However, I'd like to understand how to do this in the `ggproto` code. I also know that with `geom_point` one can override the legend shape, but *this approach does not work for* `geom_line`.

I attempted to tinker with the `GeomPath` object to change the `draw_key = draw_key_path` to `draw_key = draw_key_point`, but that failed for many reasons.

I also thought I might be able to achieve the desired effect using `guides(color = guide_geom())` but, as is broadly advertised, this is an undocumented function. I was unable to make progress even after looking at the source code on GitHub.

**The code snippet at the bottom produces the desired effect but is hacky.**

```
# this is the default
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

mydf <- tibble(month = rep(seq(1, 10, 1), 4),
           olympian = sort(rep(c("apollo", "jove", "mercury", "minerva"), 10)),
           weight = c(seq(51, 60, 1), seq(60, 78, 2), 
                    seq(69.5, 56, -1.5), seq(55, 46, -1)))

ggplot(mydf, aes(month, weight, color = olympian)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(title = "Default geom_line legend shape")
```

[image]

```
# here is what worked to achieve the effect

GeomLine2 <- GeomPath

GeomLine2$draw_key <- function(data, params, size) {
  data$linetype[is.na(data$linetype)] <- 0

  segmentsGrob(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, # NOTE CHG HERE
               gp = gpar(
                 col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha),
                 lwd = 5, # NOTE CHG HERE
                 lty = data$linetype,
                 lineend = "round" # NOTE CHG HERE
               ),
               arrow = params$arrow
  )
}

geom_line2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, 
                        stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
                        na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, 
...) 
{
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLine2, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = 
inherit.aes, 
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}

ggplot(mydf, aes(month, weight, color = olympian)) +
  geom_line2(size = 1) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(subtitle = "Hacked geom_line legend shape")
```

[image]

This code also produces the undesirable side effect of setting all future calls to `ggplot2::geom_line` to this same legend effect.

PS ... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634276/replacing-ggplot2-legend-key-for-geom-line-with-symbol) would be helpful but it is for old `ggplot2`

Comment: How does tinkering with `GeomPath` create problems? I'd have thought toggling between `environment(GeomPath$draw_key)$f <- [your customised function above]` and `environment(GeomPath$draw_key)$f <- draw_key_path` would enable you to switch between the two legend types?

Comment: I'll give the highlights since I do agree with dww below . . . changing by porting over `draw_key` from `GeomPoint` would throw errors caused by not having size & stroke specified. Also, the custom functions would fail if one didn't have functions like `keep_mid_true` involved. Finally, weird twists (like finding `Kmisc::dapply`) threw consistent wrenches in the process.

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1:

Don't do it! (NB This is my favourite and it is not intended to be facetious or unhelpful). `ggplot` tries to force you to do things in a specific way usually because there is a good reason.  Representing lines with dots is less clear than using lines, so should typically be avoided.  the most important aspect of a graph is how clearly does it convey information, not how pretty does it look.  Don't compromise clarity for aesthetics.

But, if you really have a good reason why you are sure dots will be better then ...

## Option 2

Don't use ggplot.  ggplot, as mentioned, prefers to to use its own philosophy of how graphs should be.  Other tools are more forgiving and can easily accomodate this.  E.g. this will be easy to do in base graphics

## Option 3

If you really need ggplot, and you really need dots to represent lines, then you could create a graph that uses geom_point instead of geom_line, and then use gtable to replace the legend in your line graph with the one from the points graph

```
g = ggplot(mydf, aes(month, weight, color = olympian)) + theme_light()

gt.l = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g + geom_line(size = 1)))
gt.p = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g + geom_point(size = 2)))
gt.l$grobs[15] = gt.p$grobs[15]
grid.draw(gt.l)
```

[image]

Note: if you don't know which grob needs to be replaced, you can search for `"guide"` in the grob names to find the right one:

```
gt.l$grobs[grep('guide', gt.l$layout$name)] = gt.p$grobs[grep('guide', gt.p$layout$name)]
```

Comment: thank you dww...yes agreed, I was mostly interested in this as a vehicle to better understand the `ggplot2` internals. Given the desired effect, your solution is much cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `key_glyph` argument (added with ggplot2 3.2.0 in mid-2019):

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(month, weight, color = olympian)) +
  geom_line(key_glyph = "point") +
  theme_light() +
  labs(title = "Updated geom_line legend shape")
```

[image]